# How can I highlight an option in a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` with some values in it. each value loads a different webpage.

I want the default value that always shows to be "Select page".

How can I highlight the option for the current page when the user clicks on the dropdown?

By highlight i mean either have it selected or change its background colour or something.

HTML:

```
<select id="siteId" name="siteId" onchange=".....">
    <option value="">Select a page</option>
    <option row="1" value="68067">MAIN SITE</option>
    <option row="2" value="88616">A</option>
    <option row="3" value="88617">B</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:** this select is created dynamically. I can only edit it with java-script after the page renders

Comment: Use the selected attribute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for jQuery solution then `:eq()` and `attribute selector` will be your best bet to look for. I have done something: **http://jsbin.com/ojexuh/1/edit**

first with `:eq()`

```
$('select option:eq(2)').css({"background":"green", "color":"white"});
```

and `attribute selector` like this one:

```
$('select option[row="1"]').css({"background":"red", "color":"yellow"});
```

Answer (score 2):

`option` does support background colors within a `select`. I just set up a simple class to highlight it, as seen via [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EMSZg/).

You can add a class like this

```
$('current page selector').addClass('current');
```

You could also just manually set it with the `css` function

```
$('current page selector').css('background-color', 'red');
```

You don't really have enough information for me to help you determine how to find the current page. I recommend having some way to tell from the value of the `option` that you can compare to the current `window.location`.

Comment: @svidgen interesting. Is that any browser in OS X or just webkit?

Comment: I only tested FF, Chrome, and Safari. I'm assuming it's any browser that uses **OS X's** dropdown control.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of variability in browser+OS support for this. Taking Chrome as an example, the dropdown doesn't appear to accept any styling on OS X, but on Windows, background colors can be assigned both in a stylesheet and inline style attribute:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .highlighted {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<select name='whatever'>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
    <option value='3' style='background-color: green;'>three</option>
    <option value='4' class='highlighted'>four</option>
</select>
```

Again, both methods work on windows, neither on OS X.

If you want a solution that works everywhere, you need to build your own dropdown control.

Answer (score 0):

Set selected="selected" for the option you want to be the default.

```
<option row="3" value="88617" selected="selected">B</option>
```